# Changes to list-view is undone when user logs in

Tags: list, list-view, view

First of all I must say I am new to sharepoint. I have a problem that keeps recurring for me, and I have no idea as to why.

I have a list-view (or several really on different site collections) that originally has a number of columns. Lets say 5 columns. I have to remove 2 of these, and I do this by clicking "Modify view" and deselecting the columns. Returning to my view now, the two columns I deselected are now gone. I edit the webpart showing the list and make sure that it points to my newly modified view. I make sure that the columns are erased from my templates, and everything is looking as it should from my point of view.

Until the customer logs in - for some reason the changes I did to the list view is reverted back to its original settings. I have tried many things now, even a new deploy with the new settings (I can't delete and redeploy the whole thing as it has much data in it). I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. It is not a single incident either, as I have made changes over and over, and yet every time this particular user logs in, the changes are undone.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are editing a web part, have you made sure that the page this web part is living on has been checked in, published, and approved (if necessary)? If the user goes to the newly modified view directly do they see the changes you made there?

It sounds like you are modifying a web part page where a view to the list lives and it has not been published and approved, which would be why a non-admin user would still see the old version.